# Mingw32 compilation not running C++ program but Mingw64 works fine

Tags: c++, windows, dll, mingw32

I work on Windows 10 x64, I have install mingw64 and mingw32. I wrote a C++ program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern "C" {
#include <windows.h>

#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavformat/avio.h>
#include <libavutil/audio_fifo.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/frame.h>
#include <libavutil/time.h>
#include <libavutil/timestamp.h>
#include <libavutil/macros.h>
#include <libavfilter/avfilter.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersink.h>
#include <libavfilter/buffersrc.h>
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

    printf("hello world\n");

    avformat_network_init();
    avdevice_register_all();

    return 0;
}
```

When I in mingw64 use G++ compile these code, it runs fine. but in mingw32, I use same command to compile, it cannot run, cannot even print `hello world`. I use the command:

```
g++ -g t.cpp -lavformt -lavdevice
```

Comment: What does "cannot run" mean? Is there an error message?

Comment: As an aside, that's more of a C program than C++...

Comment: Do you have 32 bit versions of those libraries? If the libraries are 64 bit you cannot use them with a 32 bit program. The first thing I would try is to remove the av library, and just try a simple hello world program, does that work?

Comment: Where is build process described? What is actual error? Build issue? Application crash (provide call stack)? Application hangs (provide call stack)? Application reports error (what error)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the answers regarding the issue I raised earlier. I have figured out the cause of the problem. The 32-bit ffmpeg library I am using was installed as a package under the mingw32 environment. However, these libraries did not include all the dependencies they rely on in the dll file. As a result, the program crashes when it cannot find the necessary dependencies. These libraries depend on more than forty other dll files, and finding all of them will take considerable time.I used the Process Monitor tool provided by Microsoft to see which DLL files were called when running the EXE file.